# Component Level Properties In Application.cfc

Tags: coldfusion, application.cfc

If I have component level properties in my application.cfc will they get evaluated every time a page is it or will they only get evaluated when the application is created?

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cfscript>
        this.name = "WARM2_Demo";
        this.applicationTimeout = CreateTimeSpan(1,0,0,0);
        this.setClientCookies = true;
        this.setDomainCookies = false;
        this.sessionManagement = true;
        this.sessionTimeout = CreateTimeSpan(0,0,30,0);
        this.clientManagement = false;
        this.scriptProtect = true;

        this.appDirectory = getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath());
        this.fileSeparator = createObject("java","java.lang.System").getProperty("file.separator");

         ....

    </cfscript>

    <cffunction name="OnApplicationStart" returntype="boolean">
        <cfscript>
            setupApplication();
            return true;
        </cfscript>
    </cffunction>

        ....

</cfcomponent>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pseudo-constructor of Application.cfc **is** executed every request.

Basically behind the scenes an instance of Application.cfc is created every request, and that instantiation behaves just like any other CFC instantiation: the pseudo-constructor bit - the stuff inside the CFCOMPONENT tags but outwith any CFFUNCTION / function declarations - is run.

After the pseudo-constructor is run, any appropriate event handler / interceptor methods are run, eg: onRequestStart().

NB: you could test this very easily yourself by just outputting something in there. It'll show up on the screen on every request (make it a getTickCount() or createUuid() call so you can see it changing).

Comment: I keep seeing "NB:" all over the place. What does it stand for?

Comment: @Adam: "NB:" stands for "Nota bene" (Latin) or "Notez bien" (French) and means "Please note:"

Answer (score 0):

evaluated every time a page is requested, I think.

stick them in `Application` scope in `onApplicationStart()`

but honestly, fileSeparator?? Just use `/`, it'll work on Windows and *nix OS just fine. :)

Comment: File separator is guaranteed to work as long as the JVM supports it.  I know that its highly unlikely but you just never know if some version of windows or other OS that this app may run on down the line won't support it.